# Copying component of struct deletes another component of the same struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I am currently learning C and have to program a "dynamic array".

In a header file provided to us, the struct DynArray is declared as

```
struct DynamicArray
{
    unsigned int size;
    unsigned int capacity;

    int *data;
};
```

I have already implemented most of the functions in the dyn_array program, which was provided with empty functions.
My difficutly lies with the function dn_append(DynamicArray *a, int elem). The only description I have been given is

```
// =====================================================================================
//         Name:  dn_append
//  Description:  Append an element.
//
//   Parameters:  a - the array
//                elem - the new value
//      Returns:  non-zero, if the array was successfully extended
// =====================================================================================
```

We have a makefile to compile this and a few test cases. In one of the test programs, a new DynArray is initialized and then a few values are appended:

```
int
main ( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    DynamicArray *a1;
    int                     i;

    a1 = dn_new ( 5 );

    dn_append ( a1,  5 );
    dn_append ( a1,  7 );
    dn_append ( a1,  8 );
    dn_append ( a1, 11 );
    dn_append ( a1, 13 );
    dn_append ( a1, 15 );

    dn_set ( a1, 2, 9 );

    for ( i = 0; i < dn_size ( a1 ); i += 1 )
    {
        printf ( "%d\n", dn_get ( a1, i ) );
    }

    dn_destory ( a1 );

    return 0;
}
```

It aborts with a segmentation fault.
My (faulty) implementation is as follows. The outer else-case is completely messed up, since the debugging drove me crazy. (Note that I explain the problematic line after the code sample.)

```
    int
dn_append ( DynamicArray *a, int elem )
{
    printf("\n\nAppend:\n");
    if (a->size >= a->capacity) {
        printf("Array too small");
        int *dataPtr = realloc(a->data, 2*a->capacity);

        if (dataPtr != NULL) {
            a->capacity *= 2;
            a->data = dataPtr;
            a->data[a->size] = elem;
            a->size++;
        }
        else {
                return 0;
        }
    }
    else {
        int *dataPtr;
        dataPtr = a->data;

        printf("Size: %d, Capacity: %d\n", a->size, a->capacity);
        int sizeN = a->size;
        printf("Size: %d, Capacity: %d\n", a->size, a->capacity);

        //int offset = sizeN;
        int *temp;
        temp = dataPtr;// + offset;
        //dataPtr[offset] = elem;
        //printf("Data at %d is %d, should be %d\n", offset, *(a->data), elem);

        a->size++;
    }

    return 1;
}
```

The problematic line is in the outer else-case, in the middle:

```
    printf("Size: %d, Capacity: %d\n", a->size, a->capacity);
    int sizeN = a->size;
    printf("Size: %d, Capacity: %d\n", a->size, a->capacity);
```

When I run the program, these lines print out

```
Size: 0, Capacity: 5
Size: 0, Capacity: 0
```

I don't even touch the `capacity`-component of the struct, but it sets it to 0, which completely f***s up the following program.

After commenting the line `int sizeN = a->size;`, the `capacity` is left right as it should.
I need to read the `size`, one way or another.

So, why the hell does it change that component?

---

Some additional infos:

```
DynamicArray*
dn_new ( unsigned int capacity )
{
    if (capacity > 0) {
        int *dataPtr = malloc(capacity*sizeof(int));

        if (dataPtr != NULL) {
            struct DynamicArray array = { 0, capacity, dataPtr };
            return &array;
        }
        else {
            return NULL;
        }
    }
    else {
        return NULL;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the type of well-written homework question that I would spend time reading and possibly answering. +1.

Comment: Please show your allocator function, and try running your code in `valgrind` and/or a debugger.

Comment: What does dn_new look like?

Comment: Probably has nothing to do with the error that you encounter, but you should print `unsigned` values with `%u`.

Comment: `valgrind` tells me, that `Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)` and that I have `Use of uninitialised value of size 8` for every line I have such a `printf()` as above. I also don't know, what an allocator function is.

Comment: Your allocator function is your `dn_new()`.

Comment: That what I'd guessed. Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6441218/can-a-local-variables-memory-be-accessed-outside-its-scope

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `dn_new()` you have:

```
if (dataPtr != NULL) {
    struct DynamicArray array = { 0, capacity, dataPtr };
    return &array;
}
```

Here, `array` is a local variable; it will be out of scope after returning it. You should allocate memory on the heap for that:

```
struct DynamicArray *array = malloc(sizeof *array);
array->size = 0;
array->capacity = capacity;
array->data = dataPtr;
return array;
```

And remember to `free()` this memory in your destructor function (`dn_destroy()`).

Comment: Thanks a lot! I tried that before, but the compiler said `excess elements in scalar initializer`, so I tried to do a workaround. Apparently I did something differently than this...

Comment: Yup, this is the problem here. By returning a local variable, it will get clobbered by future function calls.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that you mix up how you interpret your sizes and capacities. You use them as if the count the number of elements but you allocate them (with `realloc`) as number of bytes. Change your code to the following:

```
int *dataPtr = realloc(a->data, 2*a->capacity*sizeof(a->data[0]));
```

Comment: I changed that (to sizeof(int), since we only allow int values), but the problem described above still exists. Thanks a lot for that hint, though!